# Usages of let and const within for..of loop definition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm fairly well-versed on the differences between es6 `let` and `const` in general. What I'm not so sure about, is within the definition of a `for..of` loop.

I know that an "old-school" for loop signature will not accept `const`
ie

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) ... // works in chrome

for (const i = 0; i < 100; i++) ... // does not work in chrome (reassignment error)
```

However, with a `for..of` loop, it does not seem to make a difference

```
const someArray = ['hello', 'hey'];

for (let elem of someArray) ... // works
for (const elem of someArray) ... // also works?
```

So what's going on here?

Why is `const` allowed in `for..of` but not an old-school for loop?

What is the ultimate result difference within the loop? (other than possibly reassigning `elem` within the loop which I wouldn't expect many people to be doing regardless)

Comment: _You can use const instead of let too, if you don't reassign the variable inside the block._ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: `const` is *allowed* in old-school loops as well (not a syntax error). You just cannot increment it.

Comment: @Bergi yep i realized that while doing further research after asking this Q. Might as well drop this Q since it's a dupe anyway. My searches didn't find those :)

Answer (score 5):

Only one variable is reassigned hence the error

```
for (const i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

There is a separate variable created for each loop, hence, works fine

```
for (const elem of someArray)
```